# Get title of page that calls render action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Render action to inject some tabs into a calling view.  I want to be able to get the Title of the view executing the RenderAction method however in the partial view I can't seem to access the viewbag or viewdata. It was my understanding that a partial view gets a copy of the parents viewbag / viewdata dictionary.

I've tried `ViewBag.Title` and `ViewData["title"]` but nothing gets returned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `RenderAction`, the model used by that action is independent from the one that is in use when you call `RenderAction`. The same goes for `ViewBag` and `ViewData`. If your action called by `RenderAction` contains no logic, you could change it to `RenderPartial` to share the model between parent and child actions.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense.  Anyway i can pass in the title of the parent page when calling renderaction

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author in order to move it from the question post)*.

I found out that if you create a model you can pass that model into the render actions method:

```
public class ViewInfo{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

then call the renderaction method:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderTabs", "Tab", new {Title = ViewBag.Title});}
```